# CSS - Float & Resizing Windows

Tags: css, html, css-float, window-resize

I have two divs on a page and one of them is floating on the right. I've set a min-width on the div which is not floating. As I make my browser window smaller, the floating div encroaches upon the non-floating div as expected but continues past the min-width and starts to push all the text in the non-floating div down. How can I stop the floating div from moving past a certain point? I've included sample code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#one
{
    border: 1px red dotted;
    margin-right: 500px;
    min-width: 250px;
}

#two
{
   border: 1px red dotted;
   float: right;
   width: 450px;
}

</style>
</head>

<div id="container">

<div id="two">
   This is a floating div.
</div>

<div id="one">
   This div is not floating and has a whole bunch of text inside of it.
</div>

</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I managed to figure it out! I set a min-width on the container div as well and the floating div stops moving once the browser window reaches the minimum width of that container div.

Answer (score 1):

Make a wrap `<div>`:

```
<div id="wrap">
   <div id="list_events"></div>
    <div id="right_content"></div>
</div>
```

then do this:

```css
#wrap {
    min-width: 600px;
}
```

Setting `min-width` will do it.